# Link from modal in modal

Tags: hyperlink, popup, modal-dialog, virtuemart

I am using VirtueMart 2.0.10 and Joomla 2.5 and the products page is set to open in a modal popup. In this way any additions to the cart trigger a second modal (modal in modal, if you like) that includes links. At the moment the links open in the first modal that opened, but I would like the pages to open in the original window from where we started.

How do I modify the href links to open in the original window not in the modal popup? Or do I need to write some script for this?

Thanks for any help!!!